# How to exclude tag in Google Tag Manager based on specific script include in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, google-tag-manager, fusioncharts

I have to modify our Google Tag Manager container and I'm quite noob in GTM. We have a problem with IE8 and pages that used Fusion Charts. With this combination, I have a javascript error in gtm.js and I've found that it is in a Form Submit Listener. So I thought that I would add an exception on that tag. That exception would be "If isIE8 and hasFusionChartsControl". These two are variables of type "Custom Javascript" in GTM that I have defined like this :

contientFusionCharts :

```
function() { 
  var file = "fusioncharts.js";
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
  for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    if (scripts[i].src != undefined && scripts[i].src.substr(scripts[i].src.length-file.length) == file) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

estIE8 :

```
function() {
  var isIE = !!document.documentMode; // At least IE6
  var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
  if (isIE) {
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null)
            rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
    }
  }

  return (rv > -1 && rv <= 8.0);
}
```

I have tested those javascript functions and they work well on IE8. Now I have defined a trigger :
[image: My GTM trigger that is a Page View Event, triggered on Window Loaded and fire On pageHasFusionChartsControls and isIE8]

And now my tag, I only added the exception : [image]

This look all fine to me but it is still not working. I can certify that this tag is in problem because I have created an exception that look the URL for a specific page and when I browse this specific page, the js error is no longer raised. But I don't want to create an exception specifying specific page since this is a Sharepoint site and users create page as they wish. So I don't want to have to add exceptions everytime they use Fusion Charts controls in their pages. So I thought that looking for a specific html tag that is proper to Fusion Charts would be a good idea and I came to the conclusion that looking for the script include of fusioncharts.js would be a great idea.

If you have an explanation to why it is not working and alternatives solutions, that would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, here's the answer I've received on the google product forum from Simo Ahava :

> Hey
>
> Exceptions only block the event you've set them up for. So your
>   exception will ONLY block the "Window Loaded" event. Is your Tag
>   firing on that event? If your Tag is firing on the "All Pages" event,
>   it's using the Page View, and not the Window Loaded event, so you need
>   to change your Exception trigger accordingly to match the event of the
>   Tag.
>
> OR you can just create a global exception, which blocks all events
>   that match the other conditions. You do this by using a Custom Event
>   Trigger, and set the event name to .* (and check RegEx).
>
> http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/block-your-tags-with-trigger-exceptions/
>
> Simo

I've choosen to create the global exception using a Custom Event Trigger with the event name .* (using RegEx) and that worked fine.